# maintain element placement when hovering over div

Tags: html, css, position, alignment

The goal of my code is so that whenever I hover over an element it goes to the center of the page and the image is enlarged. However when I do this either either the images listed appears with a gap matching the resized element, or the unchanged elements take up the space that was freed causing issues when trying to hover over images more than once.

I'm incredibly new to html and css so bear with me if I missed something simple, was unable to find anything googling but may have just been not knowing the keywords to search for.

```css
body{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(203, 220, 236);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.container{
    display: block;
    width: 110px;
}
.img-wrapper{
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    position: inherit;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    float: left;
}
.img-wrapper:hover{
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(1deg);
    width: 1920px;
    position: relative;
    align-self: center;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.img-wrapper:hover img{
    width: 600px;
}
img{
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Portfolio</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="images\1.png" alt="drops logo 1">
                    <div class="content">Drops Logo 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">        
                    <img src="images\2.png" alt="Abstract 1">
                    <div class="content">Abstract 1</div>
                </div>         
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="images\3.png" alt="drops logo 2">
                    <div class="content">Drops Logo 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="images\4.png" alt="Abstract 2">
                    <div class="content">Abstract 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="images\5.png" alt="Abstract 3">
                    <div class="content">Abstract 3</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with the position tag but all the combinations I've tried have not worked.

Comment: I think you would need to give the image a `position: fixed` on hover. Like this you can place it relative to the window, for instance `top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;`. But you should think if this is a good way t do you. For instance, what will mobile users do (mobile has no hover!)

Comment: Please could you describe in more detail exactly what you want to happen on hover. If you don't want a gap where the img was before hover what do you want in that place?  If the gap disappears then other elements will move up to fill it for example. And do you want only the img to expand and move to the middle, not its associated text? What should happen to that on the hover?

Comment: I wanted the image as well as the text to appear in the center of the screen. I realized that the best way to do this was instead of moving the original div to the middle of the screen I needed a second div element that appears on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Is that something like this that you wanna do?
In each display() specify your resource like :

```
display('img_1.png')
```

in place of

```
display('https://dummyimage.com/600x600/a1a1a1/fff')
```

Of course, you will have to customize your style-sheet too.
And better, you may use a grid layout to place your layers as you want...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

EDIT :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    body{
        margin: 5px;
        background-color: rgb(203, 220, 236);
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    .container{
        display: block;
        width: 110px;
    }
    .img-wrapper{
        height: auto;
        width: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        position: inherit;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        float: left;
    }
    #output{
        position:fixed;
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transform: rotate(1deg) translateX(200px) translateY(80px);
        /*transform: rotate(1deg);*/
        width:600px;
        align-self: center;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        padding: 10px;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    </style>
    <script> 
        function display(ressource){
            var out = document.getElementById("output");
            out.innerHTML = "<img src=" + ressource + "alt='image'>"
        }
        function erase(){
            var out = document.getElementById("output");
            out.innerHTML = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/a1a1a1/fff" alt="drops logo 1" onMouseOver="display('https://dummyimage.com/600x600/a1a1a1/ff0000')" onMouseOut="erase()">
                    <div class="content">Drops Logo 1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">        
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/a1a1a1/fff" alt="Abstract 1" onMouseOver="display('https://dummyimage.com/600x600/a1a1a1/fff')" onMouseOut="erase()">
                    <div class="content">Abstract 1</div>
                </div>         
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/a1a1a1/fff" alt="drops logo 2" onMouseOver="display('https://dummyimage.com/600x600/a1a1a1/00ff00')" onMouseOut="erase()">
                    <div class="content">Drops Logo 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/a1a1a1/fff" alt="Abstract 2" onMouseOver="display('https://dummyimage.com/600x600/a1a1a1/0000ff')" onMouseOut="erase()">
                    <div class="content">Abstract 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/a1a1a1/fff" alt="Abstract 3" onMouseOver="display('https://dummyimage.com/600x600/a1a1a1/ff9900')" onMouseOut="erase()">
                    <div class="content">Abstract 3</div>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the image as well as the text to appear in the center of the screen. I realized that the best way to do this was instead of moving the original div to the middle of the screen I needed a second div element within the first that appears on hover.

HTML

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Portfolio</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <div class="showhim"><img src="images\1.png" alt="drops logo 1">
                        Drops Logo 1
                        <div class="showme"><img src="images\1.png" alt="drops logo 1">
                        Drops Logo 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">        
                    <div class="showhim"><img src="images\2.png" alt="Abstract 1">
                        Abstract 1
                        <div class="showme"><img src="images\2.png" alt="Abstract 1">
                            Abstract 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>         
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <div class="showhim"><img src="images\3.png" alt="drops logo 2">
                        Drops Logo 2
                        <div class="showme"><img src="images\3.png" alt="drops logo 2">
                        Drops Logo 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <div class="showhim"><img src="images\4.png" alt="Abstract 2">
                        Abstract 2
                        <div class="showme"><img src="images\4.png" alt="Abstract 2">
                        Abstract 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <div class="showhim"><img src="images\5.png" alt="Abstract 3">
                        Abstract 3
                        <div class="showme"><img src="images\5.png" alt="Abstract 3">
                        Abstract 3
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(203, 220, 236);
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: 110px;
}
.showhim{
text-align: center;
z-index: 1;
}
.img-wrapper{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.showme{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-style: italic;
    opacity: 0.0;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 630px;
}
.showhim:hover .showme{
opacity: 1.0;
}
.showhim:hover .showme img{
width: 600px;
}
img{
    width: 100px;
}
```